# Refresh an iframe using ASP/VB?

Tags: iframe, asp-classic

I have an iframe, looks like this:

```
< iframe id="PDFLetter" src="http://127.0.0.1/letterwriterasp/pdfs/test.pdf" width="60%" height="500" runat="server" scrolling="auto" >< /iframe>
```

Problem is, that pdf file is regenerated. So I need to refresh the iframe to reflect the changes to the user. I tried this:

```
    PDFLetter.Attributes("src") = ""
    PDFLetter.Attributes("src") = "http://127.0.0.1/letterwriterasp/pdfs/test.pdf"
```

But to no avail. It doesn't refresh the pdf in the iframe.

Not sure what can be done here. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing this on a postback and entering the code in the PageLoad event? If so it should work (for complete control over html you can laways just write to a Literal control although this is much heavier).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a random number at the end of the pdf name using `?randomnumber` so that it does not use a cached version of the pdf file.